# Choose only such friends (that/whom?) you can trust

Tags: conjunctions, relative-pronouns

> Choose only such friends that  you can trust.

Is using *that* in above sentence incorrect? A friend suggested to use *as* in place of *that* but I think that is horribly wrong, although replacing *as* with *whom* seems feasible but I think even *that* is fine.

Comment: Just because _as_ could be used as a replacement doesn’t mean _that_ is wrong. (One can sound better and both still be correct.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think both are wrong actually (although your meaning would be understood, I'm just being picky). I think I would actually say "as". A formulation with "whom" might be "Choose only *those* friends whom you can trust". 
For me, the use of "such" implies "as" because it qualifies who is included in the "such"

As phrases go, its possibly straying into being an archaic format but that's just the way it sounds to me. It feels like something that would be said in an 18th century novel

Comment: I agree such use of ***such*** is definitely somewhere out there on the *dated - archaic - obsolete* scale. And noting Shakespeare's [we are such stuff / as dreams are made on](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/we-are-such-stuff---as-dreams-are-made-on) I'd have to say it goes back a lot further than 18th century novels.

Comment: I was thinking Treasure Island or somesuch but I bow to your knowledge :) and thank you to whoever up-voted me.

Answer (score 0):

Both of yours are correct plus the third one that I've added:

> Choose only such friends **that** you can trust.
>
> Choose only such friends **whom** you can trust.
>
> Choose only such friends you can trust.

I think the "as" one might work, but I personally don't like it.  It doesn't sound correct to my ear, but that doesn't mean it isn't correct.  I surely wouldn't say anything if someone said that to me.